# Intercausal reasoning: Bayesian Network

Tags: bayesian-networks

**Calculate P(Accident = 1 | Traffic = 1) and P(Accident = 1 | Traffic = 1, President = 1).**

[image]

I have got an answer for P(Accident = 1 | Traffic = 1, President = 1) which is 0.15. But while applying the same scenarios for P(Accident = 1 | Traffic = 1), it does not seem to be working.

**I tried P(A=1|T=1) ==> [ P(A=1) * P(T=1|A=1) ]/P(T=1) for P(Accident = 1 | Traffic = 1)**, but I am not getting the correct answer. I am not sure what and where I missed out.

**Please explain the calculation for P(Accident = 1 | Traffic = 1)**

Comment: Please **don't cross-post duplicates**: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/249199/7828

Comment: It's an assignment question!

Comment: To be more exact, my calculation is around 0.1428 for `P(A=1 | T=1, P=1)`

Answer (score 3):

Ilanman's setup is correct, but there's a slight mix up in his numbers that produces the wrong calculations.

`P(T = 1)` should actually equal `0.1449`, and `P(A = 1, T = 1)` should equal `0.0504`, and when divided together

```
0.0504/0.1449 = 0.3478
```

The error is made when the probabilities of `P(Traffic = 1| President = 1, Accident = 0)` and `P(Traffic = 1| President = 0, Accident = 1)` are mixed up.
So the final calculation for `P(T = 1)` should actually be,

```
=(0.9*0.01*0.1) + (0.6*0.01*0.9) + (0.5*0.99*0.1) + (0.1*0.99*0.9) = 0.1449
```

and the calculation for `P(A = 1, T = 1)` is

```
= (0.01*0.1*0.9) + (0.1*0.99*0.5) = 0.0504
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing out the full joint distribution:

```
P(A,T,P) = P(P) * P(A) * P(T|P,A)
```

And use this to calculate whichever quantities you need. We want P(A = 1 | T = 1). Using conditional probability:

```
P(A = 1 | T = 1) = P(A = 1, T = 1) / P(T = 1)

P(T = 1)
  = SUM_{over A, over P}
  = P(A, P, T = 1)
  = SUM_{over A, over P} P(P)*P(A)*P(T=1|P,A)
  =   P(T=1 | A=1, P=1)*P(A=1)*P(P=1)
    + P(T=1 | A=1, P=0)*P(A=1)*P(P=0)
    + P(T=1 | A=0, P=1)*P(A=0)*P(P=1)
    + P(T=1 | A=0, P=0)*P(A=0)*P(P=0)
  = 0.9*0.01*0.1 + 0.6*0.1*0.99 + 0.5*0.9*0.01 + 0.1*0.99*0.9
  = 0.1539

P(A = 1, T = 1)
  = SUM_{over P} P(A=1, T=1, P)
  = P(A=1, T=1, P=1)             + P(A=1, T=1, P=0)
  = P(A=1)*P(P=1)*P(T=1|A=1,P=1) + P(A=1)*P(P=0)*P(T=1|A=1,P=0)
  = 0.01*0.1*0.9                 + 0.1*0.99*0.6
  = 0.0603
```

Therefore:

```
P(A = 1 | T = 1) = P(A = 1, T = 1) / P(T = 1)
                 = 0.0603 / 0.1539
                 = 0.3918
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a priori that a student George has a 30% chance of being intelligent. Now if we look at his grade in the class, we see the grade is low. Hence the probability of George being intelligent given the grade is low decreases.

```
P(i1|g3)=0.079
```

Now we went and checked the curriculum of the class and realized that the class was a difficult one. Hence the probability of George being intelligent given the grade is low and the class is difficult increases:

```
P(i1|g3,d1)=0.11
```

Now suppose Georges grade is B (g2). Hence the probability of George being intelligent given the grade as g2 increases

```
P(i1|g2)=0.175
```

Now if we consider that the class was tough too, the probability of George being intelligent given the grade as g2 and the class being tough increases

```
P(i1|g2,d1)=0.34
```

Hence in a way, we have explained away George's poor grade with the difficulty of the class. Explaining away is an instance of a general reasoning pattern called Intercausal Reasoning where causes of the same effect can interact. This intuition of providing an alternative explanation for the evidence can be made very precise.

Source: Daphne Koller course on Coursera

Answer (score 1):

For calculating P(Accident = 1 | Traffic = 1), you should follow this procedure.

```
P(A = 1 | T = 1) = P(A = 1, T = 1) / P(T = 1)
```

So first we need to calculate P(A = 1, T = 1), that is:

```
P (A = 1, T = 1) = P(T=1 , A=1 , P=0) + P(T=1, A=1, P=1 )
```

Then we have:

```
P(T=1, A=1 , p=0) = P(T=1 | A=1, p=0) p(A=1) p(p=0) = 0.5 * 0.1 * 0.99 = 0.0495
```

Following the same method you can calculate P(T=1, A=1, p=1) that would lead to 0.0009.

So:

```
P (A = 1, T = 1) = P(T=1 , A=1 , P=0) + P(T=1, A=1, P=1 ) = 0.0495 + 0.0009 = 0.0504

=>

P(A = 1 | T = 1)  = 0.0504 / P(T = 1)
```

For calculating P(T=1), you should follow the same manner. So

```
P(T=1) = P(T=1,p=0, A=0) + P(T=1, p=0, A=1) + P(T=1, p=1, A=0) + P(T=1, p=1, A=1)
```

Then

```
P(T=1, p=0, A=0 ) = P(T=1 | p=0, A=0 ) * P(p=0) * P(A=0)
```

and so on...